# How to show alert after click the button again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an alert that is triggered by a button and this alert dissapear after 3 seconds.

How can I show that alert every time we click the button ? Currently it works only once.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ex1">
  <button id="alert-trigger" data-dismiss="alert" class="btnClick">
    Trigger Alert
  </button>

  <div id="example" class="alert" role="alert"></div>

  <script type="text/template" id="alert-template">
    <p>
      <span lang="da">Merhaba</span>,
      hello,
      <span lang="ja">Hallo</span>
    </p>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      }, 3000);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your alert element?

Comment: Where is your on click method for the button?

Comment: Use interval and after button click reset again

Comment: ah sorry updated @Wimanicesir

Comment: @Haytam updated

Comment: post your html also

Comment: So you want to fade in and fade out the `.alert` div element whenever a button is clicked?

Comment: yes exactly currently it just shows one time and if i click again after the alert dissapear it does not show anything @AndrewL64

Comment: @Dicle Are you open to a pure JavaScript solution (no jQuery) for this?

Comment: anything works actually that gives me quick solution i am bit lost while trying.. @AndrewL64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *pure javaScript*, just set the default opacity of the `#example` element to 0, change the opacity to 1 whenever your `#alert-trigger` button is clicked and use the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method to change it back to 0 after 1 second.

With *jQuery*, just hide `#example` element by default and then simply use the [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) method to fade it in on click and the use the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method along with the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method to fade the element out again after a set amount of seconds.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippets** for practical examples of what I have described above:

---

### Pure JavaScript approach:

```js
/* JavaScript */

const btn = document.getElementById("alert-trigger");
const box = document.getElementById("example");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 box.style.opacity = 1;
  setTimeout(function(){box.style.opacity = 0}, 1000);
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

body {text-align: center;}#alert-trigger{background-color: green; padding: 5px; color: #FFF;}

#example {background-color: grey;padding: 10px;margin: 10px 0px;
  opacity:0; /* initial opacity value set to 0 */
  transition: all 1s; /* will fade the element instead of hiding/showing the element instantly */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button id="alert-trigger">Trigger Alert</button>

<div id="example" >
  <h2>Box Content Here:</h2>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus quia dolore cumque aliquid eaque nisi, eos praesentium delectus tempore quidem? Iure tenetur cupiditate, laborum, saepe aut alias voluptatem impedit molestias.</p>
</div>
```

### jQuery approach:

```js
/* JavaScript */

$("#alert-trigger").on("click", function(){
 $("#example").fadeIn(); // fade in the example div
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("#example").fadeOut(); // fade out the example div
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
/* CSS */

#example {display:none;} /* initially hide it by default */
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="alert-trigger">Trigger Alert</button>

<div id="example" >
  <h2>Box Content Here:</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus quia dolore cumque aliquid eaque nisi, eos praesentium delectus tempore quidem? Iure tenetur cupiditate, laborum, saepe aut alias voluptatem impedit molestias.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For the moment you don't bind any click event to that `<button>` I assume that you're looking for something like this :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //First hide the alert :
      $("#example").hide();
      
    // then bind the click :
    $("#alert-trigger").on("click", function () {
      
      $("#example").fadeIn(); // Shows the alert
      
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#example").fadeOut(); // hides it again
      }, 3000);
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ex1">
  <button id="alert-trigger" data-dismiss="alert" class="btnClick">
    Trigger Alert
  </button>

  <div id="example" class="alert" role="alert">I'm an ALERT !</div>
  
</div>
```